# Maintain ListView Item State

Tags: android

My ListActivity is bound to an ArrayAdapter where I have overriden the getView() method.  If I change the visibility of a widget in that method or modify the view's background color, those changes somehow get lost once that modified list item returns after being scrolled off the screen.  In fact, some other view in the list is picking up the changes.

How do I get the modified view to look the same when it's redisplayed after scrolling?

Comment: You might want to post the code from your getView() method so we can get a better idea what is going on. Are you checking the data's position in getView both for setting and clearing your selection values? Also, views do get reused in lists, so you'll want to check for preexisting views in your getView method as well and change their state accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you inflating a new view each time or making use of the convertView that is passed in?

Normally the Adapter tries to recycle views, only creating enough to provide smooth scrolling. The existing recycled views are passed in as convertView. You can either inflate and return a new view every time (expensive) or just re-setup the convertView (if it exists) based on position. If recycling you need to re-set all the view attributes, as there is no guarantee that the recycled view you get is the same one used for this position in the past.

It sounds like your bug is that you are not correctly re-setting all the attributes of the recycled view (convertView) to match the data for the current position.