# How to save and maintain ListView items states after scroll?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, selecteditem, custom-adapter

After looking for some answers here, I find myself in a disturbing situation where my Listview is really getting on my nerve.

Here are the questions I looked for :

[Maintain ListView Item State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868819/maintain-listview-item-state)

[How to save state of CheckBox while scrolling in ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383222/how-to-save-state-of-checkbox-while-scrolling-in-listview)

I'm using a custom adapter with a custom row as below.

My Listview is simple as it is displaying a custom row made of three elements :

1) an `ImageView` displaying contact picture cropped in a circle ;

2) a `TextView`displaying the contact full name as plain text ;

3) and finally an `ImageView` that holds the purpouse of a `CheckBox`.

Please focus on the last element. The ImageView CheckBox-like will have its `src` changed upon click.
When the user click, the ImageView will switch between a check sign and an unchecked sign according to it's previous status. Possible status are : `{checked | unchecked}`

So far so good.
But as soon as I scroll the ListView, any aforementioned change will disappear as Android recycle unused view.
Here comes the so-called `ViewHolder` pattern. Unfortunately, this pattern is failling me on two issues :

First, when scrolling, my organized-in-an-alphabetical-order listview gets disorganized.
e.g. somehow, whitout any reason, the first displayed contact name gets displayed again later on the ListView as I scrolled. That can happen with any row ! So it would seem unused view are being wrongly re-used.

Second, and in accordance to the first issue, the checked status do seem to stay, but not always and if it does stay, it may very well stay on the wrong row ... and that can happen randomly, of course. Therefore `ViewHoder` is not a viable solution.

Before discouvering the ViewHolder pattern,  I have been using a `HashMap` to store the item position upon click as followed :

```
ContactsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public final void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, final View view,
                                          final int position, final long id) {

            final ImageView check = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.checkImage);
            final TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
            final Boolean isChecked = Boolean.valueOf(checkedContactsList.isChecked(position));

            if (isChecked != null && isChecked.booleanValue() == true) {
               check.setImageDrawable(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.unchecked_sign));
               checkedContactsList.(position);
            } else {
               check.setImageDrawable(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.checked_sign));
               checkedContactsList.add(position, true);
            }
        }
    });
```

I tried adding a different value instead of `position`.
I tried with `ContactsListView.getPositionForView(view)`
And I also tried with the View's ID, but still it doesn't work.
I wish I could use `ContactsListView.getSelectedItemPosition()` but it returns `-1` as there is no selection event because I'm handling a touch/click event.

And this is how my `Custom Adapter` looks like :

```
public final View getView(final int position,
                          final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View contactRowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_row, parent, false);

    final ImageView contactPic = (ImageView) contactRowView.findViewById(R.id.contactPic);
    final TextView contactName = (TextView) contactRowView.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
    final ImageView checkImage = (ImageView) contactRowView.findViewById(R.id.checkImage);
    // the list is the same as above and therefore contains the exact same entries
    if (this.checkedContactsList.isChecked(position))
        checkImage.setImageDrawable(this.context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.checked_sign));

    contactPic.setImageBitmap(cropePictureInCircle(this.contacts.get(position).getPicture()));
    contactName.setText(this.contacts.get(position).getName());
    return contactRowView;
}
```

Is there a good way to keep the checked row checked and the unchecked row unchecked in the given alphabetical order ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

For the list position change I know the solution but for the second problem I am still searching for a solution, anyway first make a viewHolder class;

```
 public class ViewHolder{
      //put all of your textviews and image views and 
      //all views here like this
      TextView contactName;
      ImageView checkImage;
      ImageView contactImage;
 }
```

Then edit your adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    final View contactRowView = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (contactRowView == null) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE
                );

        contactRowView =
                inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_row, parent,
                        false);
        holder = new ViewHolder():
        holder.contactPic = (ImageView)
                contactRowView.findViewById(R.id.contactPic);
        holder.contactName = (TextView)
                contactRowView.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
        holder.checkImage = (ImageView)
                contactRowView.findViewById(R.id.checkImage);
        contactRowView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = contactRowView.getTag();

        // the list is the same as above and therefore      contains the exact same entries
        if (this.checkedContactsList.isChecked(position))

            holder.checkImage.setImageDrawable(this.context.get.
                    Resources().getDrawable(R.drawable.checked_sign));


        holder.contactPic.setImageBitmap(cropePictureInCircle(this.contacts.get(position).getPicture()));

        holder.contactName.setText(this.contacts.get(position).getName());
        return contactRowView;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps and sorry because writing code from my phone is totally awkward.